# Shooting method with Neumann Conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation [image]     with boundary conditions [image] using the shooting method. Also assuming y(0) and y(1) are nonzero and equal. I am having trouble setting this up, and here is a first try.

```
system[\[CapitalOmega]_] := {y1'[x] == y2[x], y2'[x] == y1[x]^2 + 2*Pi^2*Cos[2*Pi*x] - Sin[Pi*x]^4, y1[0] == \[CapitalOmega], y2[0] == \[CapitalOmega]}
myODEsoln[\[CapitalOmega]_] := NDSolve[system[\[CapitalOmega]], {y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
yend[\[CapitalOmega]_?NumericQ] := First[y1[x] /. myODEsoln[\[CapitalOmega]] /. x -> 1]
bc = FindRoot[yend[\[CapitalOmega]] == 0, {\[CapitalOmega], -5, 5}]
Plot[Evaluate[y1[x] /. myODEsoln[\[CapitalOmega] /. bc]], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 12], Style["y1(x)", 12]}]
```

Comment: If you use `myODEsoln[Ω_] := 
 NDSolve[system[Ω], {y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]` instead of what you have the code runs without any errors. Right?

Comment: Or, since $0 \leq x \leq 1$ perhaps you should use the following instead of what you have: `Plot[Evaluate[y1[x] /. myODEsoln[Ω /. bc]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 12], Style["y1(x)", 12]}]` Again no errors

Comment: But you are aware, that you can solve it directly?   `ysol = y /. 
  First[NDSolve[{Derivative[2][y][x] == 
      2*Pi^2*Cos[2*Pi*x] - Sin[Pi*x]^4 + y[x]^2, 
     Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][1] == 0}, 
    y, {x, 0, 1}]]; Plot[ysol[x], {x, 0, 1}] `